# Application crashes with error "Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU0)."

Tags: c, esp32, freertos, esp-idf

I have written following app. There is a button attached to GPIO 4 and and HC-SR04 ultrasonic range finder with TRIGGER and ECHO pin on 18 and 19 respectively. The idea is simple that when I press the button, the ultrasonic range finder should find distance and dump the value to stdout. I am using esp-idf framework to write the application. This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "driver/timer.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/queue.h"
#include "freertos/timers.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "esp_log.h"

#define TIMER_DIVIDER         (16)  //  Hardware timer clock divider
#define TIMER_SCALE           (TIMER_BASE_CLK / TIMER_DIVIDER)  // convert counter value to seconds
#define ESP_INTR_FLAG_DEFAULT 0

#define BUTTON_PIN 4
#define TRIGGER_PIN 18
#define ECHO_PIN 19
static const char *TAG = "my project";

static volatile uint8_t btn_history = 0;
static xQueueHandle s_queue_timer;
static xQueueHandle s_queue_trigger;
static xQueueHandle s_queue_echo;

void task_trigger_end(void *pvParameters);
static bool IRAM_ATTR isr_trigger_expiry(void *args);
void task_handle_echo(void *pvParameters);

typedef struct {
    int error;
    uint64_t timer_value;
} echo_timer_event;

static void start_timer(int group, int timer, bool auto_reload, int inter_microsecond, timer_isr_t callback_function)
{
    esp_err_t error;

    timer_config_t btn_timer = {
        .divider = 16,
        .counter_dir = TIMER_COUNT_UP,
        .counter_en = TIMER_PAUSE,
        .alarm_en = TIMER_ALARM_EN,
        .auto_reload = auto_reload,
    };
    error = timer_init(group, timer, &btn_timer);
    if (error == ESP_OK)
        ESP_LOGI(TAG,"timer initialized\n");
    error = timer_set_counter_value(group, timer, 0);
    if (error == ESP_OK)
        ESP_LOGI(TAG,"counter value set\n");
    error = timer_set_alarm_value(group, timer, inter_microsecond);
    if (error == ESP_OK)
        ESP_LOGI(TAG,"alarm value set\n");
    error = timer_enable_intr(group, timer);
    if (error == ESP_OK)
        ESP_LOGI(TAG,"interrupt enabled\n");
    error = timer_isr_callback_add(group, timer, callback_function, NULL, 0);
    if (error == ESP_OK)
        ESP_LOGI(TAG,"isr callback added\n");
    printf("group is: %d and timer is %d",group,timer);
    error = timer_start(group, timer);
    if (error == ESP_OK)
        ESP_LOGI(TAG,"timer started\n");
}

void handle_button_press( void *pvParameters)
{
    // Variable to hold the data received
    uint8_t press_flag = 0;
    while (1) {
        xQueueReceive(s_queue_timer, &press_flag, portMAX_DELAY);
        if (press_flag == 1) {
            printf(".");
            fflush(stdout);
            gpio_config_t trig_io;
            trig_io.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_DISABLE;
            trig_io.mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT;
            trig_io.pin_bit_mask = 1ULL<<TRIGGER_PIN;
            trig_io.pull_down_en = GPIO_PULLDOWN_DISABLE;
            trig_io.pull_up_en = GPIO_PULLUP_DISABLE;
            gpio_config(&trig_io);

            esp_err_t error;
            error = gpio_set_level(TRIGGER_PIN, 1);
            if (error != ESP_OK)
                ESP_LOGE(TAG,"can't set gpio level\n");
            else
                ESP_LOGI(TAG,"gpio set\n");
            xTaskCreate(task_trigger_end,"Handle Trigger End", 50000, NULL, 5, NULL);
            start_timer(TIMER_GROUP_1, TIMER_0, false, 20, isr_trigger_expiry);
        }
    }
}

static bool IRAM_ATTR isr_trigger_expiry(void *args)
{
    BaseType_t high_task_awoken = pdFALSE;
    int triggered_flag = 1;
    xQueueSendFromISR(s_queue_trigger, &triggered_flag, NULL);
    return high_task_awoken == pdTRUE;
}

static bool IRAM_ATTR isr_echo_timeout(void *args)
{
    BaseType_t high_task_awoken = pdFALSE;
    echo_timer_event evt = {
        .error = 1,
        .timer_value = 76000
    };
    xQueueSendFromISR(s_queue_echo, &evt, NULL);
    return high_task_awoken == pdTRUE;
}

static bool IRAM_ATTR gpio_isr_handler(void *args)
{
    BaseType_t high_task_awoken = pdFALSE;
    // printf("isr handler\n");
    echo_timer_event evt = {
        .error = 0,
        .timer_value = timer_group_get_counter_value_in_isr(TIMER_GROUP_0, TIMER_0)
    };
    xQueueSendFromISR(s_queue_echo, &evt, NULL);
    return high_task_awoken == pdTRUE;
}

void task_trigger_end(void *pvParameters)
{
    int trigger_fired_flag = 0;
    while (1) {
        xQueueReceive(s_queue_trigger, &trigger_fired_flag, portMAX_DELAY);
        if(trigger_fired_flag == 1) {
            gpio_reset_pin(TRIGGER_PIN);
            
            // Configure echo pin for input
            gpio_config_t io_conf;
            io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_POSEDGE;
            io_conf.pin_bit_mask = 1ULL<<ECHO_PIN;
            io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
            io_conf.pull_down_en = 1;
            gpio_config(&io_conf);

            // Configure interrupt on rising edge
            gpio_install_isr_service(ESP_INTR_FLAG_EDGE);
            gpio_isr_handler_add(ECHO_PIN, gpio_isr_handler, NULL);

            printf("before creating task\n");
            // Create echo handling task
            xTaskCreate(task_handle_echo, "Handle Echo Timer", 50000, NULL, 5, NULL);

            // start echo timer
            start_timer(TIMER_GROUP_1, TIMER_0, false, 76000, isr_echo_timeout);
            vTaskDelete(NULL);
        }
    }
}

void task_handle_echo(void *pvParameters)
{
    echo_timer_event evt;
    printf("task cratedk\n");
    while (1) {
        xQueueReceive(s_queue_echo, &evt, portMAX_DELAY);
        if (evt.error)
            break;
        printf("value is %llu\n", evt.timer_value);
    }
    printf("killing me\n");
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

static bool IRAM_ATTR btn_press_isr (void *args)
{
    BaseType_t high_task_awoken = pdFALSE;
    int true_flag = 1;

    btn_history = btn_history << 1;
    btn_history |= (uint8_t) gpio_get_level(BUTTON_PIN);

    if (btn_history == 0b01111111)
        xQueueSendFromISR(s_queue_timer, &true_flag, &high_task_awoken);
    
    return high_task_awoken == pdTRUE;
}

void app_main(void)
{
    // Configure button pin for input
    gpio_config_t io_conf;
    io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_PIN_INTR_DISABLE;
    io_conf.pin_bit_mask = 1ULL<<BUTTON_PIN;
    io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
    io_conf.pull_up_en = GPIO_PULLUP_DISABLE;
    io_conf.pull_down_en = GPIO_PULLDOWN_ENABLE;
    gpio_config(&io_conf);
    
    // Queue to receive the button press events.
    s_queue_timer = xQueueCreate(10, sizeof(int));
    s_queue_trigger = xQueueCreate(10, sizeof(int));
    s_queue_echo = xQueueCreate(10, sizeof(echo_timer_event));

    // Configure and start timer to read the current status of the button all times
    start_timer(TIMER_GROUP_0, TIMER_0, true, 1000, btn_press_isr);

    // Create a task to take action on button press
    xTaskCreate(handle_button_press,"Handle Press Task", 50000, NULL, 5, NULL);
}
```

I have previously tested code upto the pressing of button and the timer and interrupt are working fine. The code runs up until the ECHO pin is initialised at which point it crashed with the error in post title.

Also I am using devkitc as development board and it doesn't have the JTAG port I guess so I am confined to using printfs to debug. Is there a better way to debug RTOS based apps on esp32?

Comment: You don't have any error checking. Your calls to `xQueueCreate`, `xTaskCreate`, `start_timer`, `xQueueReceive`, etc. could fail, and you'll never know. You're passing 50 KB of RAM to each task, which is about 10 times more than they need and might deplete your heap really fast, causing all sorts of failures. You can debug the app if you buy the ESP-Prog and connect it to the JTAG pins of the devkit.

Comment: You don't need a specific JTAG port. You just need GPIO12, 13, 14 and 15 available (as well as GND). DevkitC boards should have these pins available.

Comment: If you look at the monitor output when the crash occurs, there should be messages showing the path through the software that got to the crash. Can you show some of your monitor output rather than just paraphrasing the error message?